# vsftpd can't upload to mounted directory

Tags: ftp, mount, vsftpd, chown, chgrp

I have read many, many help pages today trying to fix this, and I'm still nowhere closer.

vsftpd config file:

```
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
cmds_allowed=PASV,SIZE,CWD,PWD,MKD,RMD,STOR,DELE,TYPE,RETR,LIST,QUIT
local_umask=022
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_std_format=YES
listen=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
```

I can connect and upload to the user's home directory fine. However my www directory is also mounted in there, and while I can browse it, I cannot upload.

```
[15:36:27] [R] STOR favicon.gif
[15:36:27] [R] 553 Could not create file.
[15:36:27] [R] Transfer Failed: favicon.gif
```

You will ask me to check permissions, and I have. All directories are 755. They are owned by root but chgrp'd to 'webroot', which is a group my local user and the vsftpd are members of.

Still can't upload anything, same error, and I'm tearing my hair out. Help!

Comment: Permissions should be 775 for group to be able to write.

Comment: `userlist_file=/etc/vsftpd.users` holds all your users. See if www/username is there and if so uncomment it and reload vsftpd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`755` means `read/write/execute` for owner and `read/write` for group an others. In order to allow group members to write in that folder set folder permissions to `775`.